# menu bar color not changed in safari

Tags: css, html

i have customize the css to change the color of menubar for my magento website, it is working fine for google chrome and mozila firfox but in safari browser menubar color is showing white it don't know what is the problem.  here is my site http://www.flirtwithhair.com/classic/

my css code after changes

```
.nav-container {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #940c94 0%, #f4f1f1 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #eae5e4;
}
```

changes done : #ffffff   to  #940c94

Comment: This does not belong here as it has nothing to do with Magento directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add -webkit property

```
.nav-container {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #940c94 0%, #f4f1f1 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #940c94 0%, #f4f1f1 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #eae5e4;
}
```